# Seek clarification on the derivation for length of a curve

Tags: integration

I come across this derivation for the length of a curve and wondering how the log function comes about? (see picture below)

Length of curve derivation is as follows $:$

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTgCC.jpg

Comment: Looks like a typo.

Comment: I also think it might be a typo but not very sure because it is not stated in the book's latest official errata (and this screenshot is from a much older edition).